# Range sum in vba

Tags: excel

What would be the fastest way to perform vector addition (n rows, 1 column) over 4000 times in excel?

I think UDF will be too slow, would you recommend? I want to add up ranges that have the same name, same dimensions, and are locally defined across multiple sheets.

EDIT: I tried the UDF and 5000 of them were too slow:

```
Function NamedRangeExists(ws As Worksheet, strRangeName As String) As Boolean

    Dim rngExists  As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngExists = ws.Range(strRangeName)
    NamedRangeExists = True
    If rngExists Is Nothing Then NamedRangeExists = False
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Function sumName(rangeName As String) As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile

    sumName = 0

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If NamedRangeExists(ws, rangeName) Then
            sumName = sumName + ws.Range(rangeName).Value
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: *What would be the fastest way...*?  There is no substitute for testing. You *think* the UDF will be too slow, but is it really? What else have you tried?  Is it faster, or slower?

Comment: Yes I tried udf and it was too slow

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be to use array formulas. The easiest way is probably a UDF.
If you use a VBA UDF with over 4000 calls you will hit the VBE refresh slowdown bug: you need to initiate calculation from VBA.

The UDF would need to be a multi-cell array UDF :
Select cells where you want the answer that are the same shape as your named ranges
Type the UDF formula into the formula bar
Press Control-Shift-Enter

here is some sample code

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub DoCalc()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
Function sumName2(rangeName As String) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile
    Dim vArr As Variant
    Dim vSum As Variant
    Dim oNM As Name
    Dim j As Long
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set oNM = NamedRange(ws, rangeName)
        If Not oNM Is Nothing Then
            If Not IsArray(vSum) Then
            ' create vsum array first time only
                vSum = ws.Range(oNM).Value2
            Else
            ' fetch array of values and add to vsum
                vArr = ws.Range(oNM).Value2
                For j = 1 To UBound(vSum)
                    vSum(j, 1) = vSum(j, 1) + vArr(j, 1)
                Next j
            End If
        End If
    Next
    sumName2 = vSum
End Function
Function NamedRange(ws As Worksheet, rangeName As String) As Name
    Set NamedRange = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set NamedRange = ws.Names(rangeName)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Charles for this very clear and extensive answer. I noticed that it requires a slight adjustment to work properly: vSum = vSum + ws.Range(oNM).Value2, otherwise we are overwriting vSum

Comment: Unfortunately addition across multiple 3 row x 1 col ranges does not work though...

Comment: No: the code given works correctly for me: it only overwrites the Vsum array the first time, thereafter its an array (assuming that your named range refers to more than one cell). And it works fine for me with multiple ranges. Are you sure that your Defined Name refers to multiple cells, and that you have correctly entered the UDF as a multi-cell array formula?

Comment: I will check: in the question text I mentioned nx1 column size, so I tested it with 1x1 as well. The change I mentioned in the first comment makes 1x1 work but apparently breaks all multicell ones.

Comment: The code is only demo code to enable you to test performance: it contains no error handling and assumes that you are always handling vectors rather than scalars. I will leave it to you to develop it to a production level for your particular circumstances.